# Recursively tree traversal and return each output as a string python

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

Essentially I have this binary tree:

[image]

What I want to do is traverse it, so I get a **str** returned to me, which has value **+BA**. Inorder to do this, I have the following function:

```
def order(root):

    if (root != None):
        root.visit() # this calls a binary tree function that just prints out root.data
        order(root.right)
        order(root.left)
```

This works well and good, but I need to return a **str** instead of printing each traversal. I tried creating a str, and doing **str += root.visit()**, but this resetted every time, so in the end it didn't work. How can I return a string with all the traversals in it?

What I tried:

```
def order(root):
    rep = ""
    if (root != None):
        rep += root.visit()
        order(root.right)
        order(root.left)

    return rep
```

Comment: Could you attach an example that **did not** work for you?

Comment: Sure I did something very basic like this: check the edited post

Comment: You didn't append `order(root.left)` nor `order(root.right)` to `rep`.

Comment: maintain an accumulator and make sure to `return` your recursive calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to preorder-traverse a binary tree you should follow this scheme:

```
def traverse(node):
    rep = ""
    if node is not None:
        rep += node.visit()
        rep += traverse(node.right)
        rep += traverse(node.left)
    return rep
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
def order(root):
    return '' if root is None else root.visit() + order(root.right) + order(root.left)
```

Or as an `if` statement:

```
def order(root):
    if root is None:
        return ''
    return root.visit() + order(root.right) + order(root.left)
```

Comment: You should just use a full if-else statement to maintain readability.

Comment: I find this very readable, it almost reads like natural language. Taste may differ.

Comment: You should also use `is` and not `==` when [comparing to None](http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.co.il/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html).

Comment: Can you do it in full if statement plase?